# The squirrel's riddle - how many marks on the tree trunk?

Tags: candy-box-2

"How many marks can you find on its trunk?" - I assume one does not have to calculate, as the riddle might be about the tree the squirrel sit's on. I counted the visible "marks" several ways, none of them was correct. Which is?

Answer (score 5):

You have to count the marks on the tree that the squirrel is sitting on. Only the marks on the trunk, the ones on the branch don't count.

The answer is

> 10

Comment: Thanks. I missed to scroll down a bitz, so i didn't saw the 10th mark...